# ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

```
CREATE TABLE Patient (
  Patient_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  First_name VARCHAR(20),
  Last_name VARCHAR(20),
  Age INT,
  Registration_date DATE,
  Sex VARCHAR(1),
  Adress VARCHAR(25),
  Blood_group VARCHAR(5),
  Doctor_id INT,
  Branch_id INT
 );
```

This is my table

```
INSERT INTO Patient VALUES (600, 'Hasib' , 'Ahmad' , 24 , 2019-09-17 ,'M', '187,Mainland', 'B +ve',NULL,NULL);
```

This is my insertion but I am getting error showing ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. Help me get rid of it.

Comment: 2019-09-17 should be quoted

Comment: But not quoting it should throw an invalid date error not a wrong value count in mysql so what are you using other than mysql?

Answer (score 1):

You must give the date as string like : **'2019-09-17'**

change your query to:

```
INSERT INTO Patient VALUES (600, 'Hasib' , 'Ahmad' , 24 , '2019-09-17' ,'M', '187,Mainland', 'B +ve',NULL,NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The date needs to be surrounded with single quotes.

Also, you should enumerate all the columns that you want to `insert` to; that's a good practice in SQL coding, and it makes it easier to backtrack what is happening when things go wrong. Since you are inserting `NULL` values in the last two columns, so I removed them from the query.

```
INSERT INTO Patient (
    Patient_ID, 
    First_Name, 
    Last_Name, 
    Age, 
    Registration_date, 
    Sex, 
    Address, 
    Blood_group
)
VALUES (
    600, 
    'Hasib', 
    'Ahmad', 
    24,
    '2019-09-17',
    'M',
    '187,Mainland', 
    'B +ve'
);
```